# Tracking two fingers fully independently

Tags: android, multi-touch, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm developing an app in which I can press 2 buttons simultaneously. My phone has Android 2.3.7 (Gingerbread API 10). I'm been looking for information and I've found that I can check if my phone can track two fingers fully independently with the PackageManager:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
if (pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT))
    ShowToast("Distinct: Yes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
else
    ShowToast("Distinct: No", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

This code tells me not. My phone hasn't the system feature FEATURE_TOUCHSCREEN_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT. But trying the application "Test your Android" in my phone I've seen that my mobile phone yes, can. In my phone I can do something like this photo: https://lh4.ggpht.com/SERDbt6S4Iz4sdWMCJqlpcN2ZSJm4nBleXVSHFB9KIdphDCldhW9-LoPxInFPeky2g4=h900
Also, I've tested some applications that I can touch 2 buttons simultaneously.
The question is: Can I do something for my phone to recognize 2 presses at once or can recognizes two press buttons at once?

I asked here as a last resort, since I've searched this solution for days.

Answer (score 0):

You can track two or more fingers in Android (and based on your image, your phone supports it), you can get the screen coordinates of where this touch is happening.The touches generate a MotionEvent and from this you can get the coordinates of the touches.

To know how many fingers are touching the screen, use:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    int count= ev.getPointerCount();
```

Also, to filter the MotionEvents to capture only press gestures, you can use MotionEvent.DOWN
inside onTouchEvent()

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    //do something with the touch
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN

These answer shows you the code to catch and use the MotionEvent and has a link to a tutorial:

[multiple-finger-input-for-android-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643152/multiple-finger-input-for-android-development)

I hope this is what you are asking

Comment: Thanks, but with your solution I only can press one button while. I have placed two buttons and in the onTouchEvent I have wrote this: Log.i("Button:", "Down"); When I touch both at once, the log only shows one time the message "Button: Down"

Comment: Yes that is correct, it will only print DOWN once, but getPointerCount() should return 2. Please have a look at the for-loop they use in the link I provided. They get the coordinates for both touches

Comment: Yes, you're right. With SurfaceView I can get the position of the two pointers. I've noticed that what I want (two buttons touched simultaneously) is impossible. Instead, I must use a SurfaceView (with Canvas) and to emulate buttons I will use the method drawRoundRect(). For the button text I will use drawText(). This solution is much more difficult, but the only possible. Thanks a lot fersarr!

Comment: :) Glad you got it to work! If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.